# Hyperledger Composer - I have a problem starting my business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to start up my business networt. It worked fine before but, after failing to upgrade my network, it doesn't seem to work...

I deleted all the cards that I have and started again from generating the business network but, still doesn't work.

When I try to import the bna file on playground, I get this saying that it is an unsupported file type.

`composer network start --networkName medrec --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card`

> ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError:
>   require is not defined Command failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all cards and restart Hyperledger Fabric.

This worked for me most of the time, fixing the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Do you know what seems to be the problem here? I don't want to repeat it again.